# Stop expanding wildcard symbols in command line arguments to Java

Tags: java, shell, cmd, wildcard-expansion

My program has to watch for files which match a mask. The folder name and mask are passed through command line arguments. But the mask is replaced by the first match  before I can use it!

Double quotes have no effect and other symbols too. I tried using `\` or `'` to protect the input. However then this symbol will be added to the args, which I do not want. Any idea of how to fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(args[0]);
    String mask = args[1];
    System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(mask);
    String regex = args[2];
    System.out.println(regex);
}
```

Regular expression from `args[2]` also replaced with some file from folder.

```
Input: "E:\Programming\Java\Task7" *.??? ...
Ouput: E:\Programming\Java\Task7 .git Task7.iml

Input: "E:\Programming\Java\Task7" *.????* [a-zA-Z]
Output: E:\Programming\Java\Task7 .idea [a-zA-Z]

Input: "E:\Programming\Java\Task7" '.???' ...
Output: E:\Programming\Java\Task7 '.???' ...

Input: "E:\Programming\Java\Task7" \\'.???'\\ ...
Output: E:\Programming\Java\Task7 \'.???'\ ...
```

I understand that using quote or backslash isn't that bad idea, but I think there exists better way.

Comment: This problem is caused by a known bug in the JVM, documented here:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131329 See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037375/trailing-asterisks-on-windows-jvm-command-line-args-are-globbed-in-cygwin-bash-s/37081167#37081167

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Background: On Linux, it is not Java that is expanding the wildcards in the command arguments.  The shell does it *before the `java` command is launched*.

The way to stop the shell from expanding wildcards is to quote the arguments.  How you do this depends on the shell you are using.

---

Now for the Windows case ... which is what you are really asking about.

From what I have read, the standard "cmd.exe" shell (in its various versions / flavours) does NOT do wildcard expansion.  It is left to the application to do expansion (or not) on an ad-hoc basis.

Obviously this is problematic for the Java "write once, run everywhere" philosophy, so the Java designers have tried to make wild-cards in command line arguments work on Windows like they do on Unix and Linux.  But unfortunately, they can't do a perfect job of this ... hence this anomaly.

However, according to [this page](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/wildcard.html), putting *double quotes* around an argument tells Java to not do wild-card expansion.

But if this doesn't help, you are probably out of luck.

---

Here are some links to Oracle documentation on this topic, taken from Oracle Java bug report [#5036373](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5036373):

> Java Wildcard expansion on Windows platform has been documented.  See
>   the following links:
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
>
> Wildcard expansion does not work in a Windows command shell for a
>   single element classpath due to the Microsoft bug described in:
>   http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98756/vs2005-setargv-obj-wildcard-handling-broken.
>
> The limitations are also mentioned in 7u10 release notes:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u10-relnotes-1880995.html

However, I think that the Oracle employee who wrote that was being *deliberately obtuse*, because the wildcard expansion in general is patently NOT documented in those "manual" pages.  They only talk about wildcard expansion in the `-cp` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the possibility, to quote the arguments which should not be expanded, there is another possibility. You can use a command-line argument file. The wildcards in parameters which are specified there are not expanded.

At least, it is so described here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-4856361B-8BFD-4964-AE84-121F5F6CF111.
See there the section "java Command-Line Argument Files".

> The launcher doesn’t expand wildcards that are present within an argument file.