# How can I execute .jar file from the terminal without specifying its name

Tags: java, cmd

How can I execute .jar file in folder from the Windows cmd without specifying its name.

I have tried below command (as there is only 1 jar in that folder I used *) but its not working(Error: Unable to access jarfile *.jar
).

```
java -jar *.jar
```

Comment: *"... but its not working"*.  What does it say?

Comment: @StephenC,its showing error Error: Unable to access jarfile *.jar

Comment: Does it work if you execute it without using a `*` ?

Comment: nope,It is only executing if am giving full name of jar like "java -jar abc.jar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure it would be a good idea to just run everything in a directory, but you could:

```
FOR %A IN ("*.jar") DO (java -jar "%~A")
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you appear to be asking is how to run the command

```
 % java -jar somelongname.jar
```

as

```
 % java -jar *.jar
```

to avoid some typing.  That's not possible, because neither the Windows CMD shell or the `java` command is going to expand the `*.jar` wildcard pattern.

(On Linux / Unix / MacOS, the shell does wildcard expansion before passing arguments to a command.  On Windows, it is the responsibility of the command to do this.  In practice, it appears that the `java` command only expands wildcards in the arguments that are going to be passed to your application; see [Stop expanding wildcard symbols in command line arguments to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948706/stop-expanding-wildcard-symbols-in-command-line-arguments-to-java.))

So if you want to avoid typing those pesky characters on Windows, you will need to do something like:

- write a simple BAT file to run "java -jar somelongname.jar", or
- write a clever BAT file to identify and run a JAR file that matches "*.jar", or
- use Powershell.

---

For what it is worth, I think what you are trying to do is rather dangerous.  This is a bit like typing "di*" to run the "dir".  What if there is some other more dangerous command on the PATH that is going to match instead of "dir"?